# REACT - Generate number automaticaly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help.
I'm trying to generate a random number in this code {number} every given second.
How can i do this?

I tried this, it generates the number randomly but doesn't update it every second.

var number;

```
    (function repeat() {
       number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
       setTimeout(repeat, 1000);
       setInterval(repeat, 1000);
    })();
```

import React from 'react'
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

```
    render() {
        const { text } = this.props

        const ProgressContainer = styled.div`
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        `
        const Text = styled.span`
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: Poppins;
            color: #fff;
        `

        const Value = styled.span`
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: Poppins;
            color: #fff;
            float: right;
        `
        const ColorAnimation = keyframes`
            0%  {background: #04e5e5;}
            10% {background: #f37055;}
            20% {background: #ef4e7b;}
            30% {background: #a166ab;}
            40% {background: #5073b8;}
            50% {background: #04e5e5;}
            60% {background: #07b39b;}
            70% {background: #6fba82;}
            80% {background: #5073b8;}
            90% {background: #1098ad;}
            100% {background: #f37055;}
        `
        const Progress = styled.div`
            height: 5px;
            border-radius: 2.5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            transition: 2s;
            animation: ${ColorAnimation} 10s infinite alternate;
        `
      
        
     return(
            <ProgressContainer>
                <Text>{text}</Text>
                <Value>{number}%</Value>
                <Progress style={{width: `${number}%`}}></Progress>
            </ProgressContainer>
        )
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the `useEffect` hook, you can create the needed `setInterval` and clean up when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    ** code for random number goes here **
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

In order to have the component re-render when ever the random number changes, you can utilize the `useState` hook:

```
const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(null);
```

Putting it all together:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Container = () => {
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setRandomNumber(Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1))
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (<div>{randomNumber}</div>)
}
```

You can see it in action [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasonmlutz/o8dj7y4z/).